# Android beacon library slow search

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon, eddystone

I use Android beacon library for beacons scanning.

I have kontakt.io beacons. In beacon settings I set 20ms interval.
Beacon is eddystone.

I think that default lenght of scan is 1,1s. I don´t override this in my code.

But there is a lot of scan that don´t find my beacon.
Is there any way to identify beacon faster?

Thank you for answers.

Comment: What version of Android are you on? (I've been using BLE Beacons and noticed it varies with device and Android verson

Comment: You could use iBeacon Scanner Android: https://github.com/inthepocket/ibeacon-scanner-android. In my experience it finds beacons more quicly.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have the beacon transmitter set to send a packet every 20ms, then the report of "a lot of scan that don´t find my beacon" is not normal.  **This is not expected behavior.**

A few things to try:

1. Turn off WiFi to see if you see the same results.   Some Android devices have WiFi chips that interfere with Bluetooth communications.
2. Try a software beacon transmitter coming from your computer or a different mobile device.  You can use the free Locate Beacon app for [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8) and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en).  The Android version will transmit Eddystone, but for iOS you must transmit iBeacon.  If you have a Mac, you can also use [MacBeacon](http://store.radiusnetworks.com/products/macbeacon).  This test will let you know if there is a problem with the beacon transmitter.
3. Try running the code on a different Android device to see if you see the same thing.  There may be an issue with the Android device's ability to detect beacons.

Comment: Thank you. Please I have one more question. If the scan is running and receive some frame from beacon, after that is stop actualy scan? I have always only one frame from one scan period. Is there any way to continue scan and same frame to some buffer? Thank you @davidgyoung

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand the question.